# Does converting this GPG encryption bash script to powershell make sense? Is there a more simple methodolgy?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, encryption, gnupg

I want to convert this BASH script into something a little more Windows friendly. I assume PowerShell is the way to go. So I found this Powershell script online that's a wrapper for the pgp2.exe. So I understand the function for encrypting the data, but I'm lost on how to code a temporary directory. So my question is what is the PowerShell logic that would follow to build a temporary sub-directory, create a path & file to then be encrypted. I am not familiar with PowerShell or the Windows 10 cmd terminal. So if anyone has any resources for converting this bash script into something more Windows 10 friendly, that would be helpful.

PS: I am not asking about syntax conversion. I'm looking more for the broad stroke logic and commands behind the Windows 10 language.

```sh
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# generate a file of random size with random bytes
# select a format generated file and encrypt/compress 
# shred original generated file
# input: temp sub-directory path with filename
# -----------------------------------------------------------
do_a_file () {
    filename="${1}"
    filesize=0
    while [[ $filesize -lt 1024 ]]; do
        filesize=$(($RANDOM % 19999999))
done
dd if=/dev/urandom of="${filename}" bs=1 count=$filesize status=noxfer conv=notrunc,noerror 2> /dev/null
random_pass=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 status=noxfer 2> /dev/null | sha512sum - | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
extension=$(($RANDOM % 3))
case "${extension}" in
0)
  # by default creates output file with .gpg extension
  gpg -q --yes --passphrase "${random_pass}" -c "${filename}" &> /dev/null 
  ;;
1)
  tempfile="${filename}.rar"
  rar a -o+ -hp"${random_pass}" "${tempfile}" "${filename}" &> /dev/null 
  ;;
2)

  tempfile="${filename}.7z"
  7za a -y -mhe=on -p"${random_pass}" "${tempfile}" "${filename}" &> /dev/null 
  ;;
esac
shred -n 1 -zu "${filename}"
}
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# split sub-directory path into array
# determine which subdirectory ($RANDOM % sizeof array)
# input: full sub-directory path
# -----------------------------------------------------------
pick_durr () {
    subdir_path="${1}"
    durr=""
    d=0
    durrs=()
    while true; do
        next_dir=${subdir_path%%/*}
        subdir_path=${subdir_path#*/}
        durrs[$d]=${next_dir}
        ((++d))

        if [[ ${subdir_path} == ${next_dir} ]]; then
            break;
        fi
    done

    subdir_count=${#durrs[@]}
    num_subdir=$(($RANDOM % $subdir_count))
    d=0
    while [[ $d -lt $num_subdir ]]; do
        durr="${durr}/${durrs[$d]}"
        ((++d))
    done
    echo ${durr}
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# determine number of words in filename ($RANDOM % 5) + 1
# grab random words from wordlist
# concatenate together for filename
# -----------------------------------------------------------
build_filename () {
    filename=""
    nameword_count=0
    num_namewords=$(($RANDOM % 5))
    num_words=$(wc -l "${wordlist}" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    ((++num_namewords))
    ((++num_words))
    while [[ $nameword_count -lt $num_namewords ]]; do
        rand_line=$(($RANDOM % $num_words))
        rand_word=$(sed -n "$rand_line p" "${wordlist}")
        if [[ $nameword_count -eq 0 ]]; then
            filename="${rand_word}"
        else
            filename="${filename}_${rand_word}"
        fi
        ((++nameword_count))
    done
    echo "${filename}"
}
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# generate a sub-directory path
# select number [0, 12] of sub-directories to create
# grab $num_subdirs of random words from wordlist
# concatenate together for sub-directory path 
# -----------------------------------------------------------
build_path () {
    num_subdirs=$(($RANDOM % 13))
    if [[ $num_subdirs -eq 0 ]]; then 
        echo 
        return 0
    fi
    subdir_count=0
    subdir_path=""
    num_words=$(wc -l "${wordlist}" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    ((++num_words))
    while [[ $subdir_count -lt $num_subdirs ]]; do
        rand_line=$(($RANDOM % $num_words))
        rand_word=$(sed -n "$rand_line p" "${wordlist}")
        subdir_path="${subdir_path}/${rand_word}"
        ((++subdir_count))
    done
    echo "${subdir_path}"
}
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# build out sub-directory structure and create path
# select number [9001, (9001 + $RANDOM)] of files to generate
# generate filename
# select temporary sub-directory path
# create the encrypted/compressed file
# repeat for specified number of iterations
# input: working directory, number of iterations
# -----------------------------------------------------------
main () {                                               # main function, durr
    num_files=0                                         # number of files to generate
    loop_count=0                                        # count number of iterations passed
    while [[ $loop_count -lt "${2}" ]]; do              # iterations  
        subdurr_path=$(build_path)                      # build a sub-directory path
        mkdir -p "${1}/${subdurr_path}"                 # create the sub   directory path
        while [[ $num_files -lt 9001 ]]; do             # generate over 9000 files
            num_files=$RANDOM                           # select number of files to generate

        done                                            # end set num_files loop
        while [[ $num_files -gt 0 ]]; do                # number of files
            filename=$(build_filename)                  # create filename
            subdurr=$(pick_durr ${subdurr_path})        # select sub-directory
            do_a_file "${1}/${subdurr}/${filename}"     # generate the file
            ((--num_files))                             # decrement file count
        done                                            # end of number of files loop



        ((++loop_count))                                # increment loop count
    done                                                # end of iterations loop
    yes | rm -rf "${1}" &> /dev/null                    # unlink encrypted files
}                                                       # end of main function
```

Comment: Too hard to read, Can you please delete the blank lines between lines of code? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I formatted it for easier reading. I'll do more researching in the mean time.

Comment: Are you making any progress on this? I'm surprized no powershell people took you up on this, although such Qs are considered off-topic here on S.O. ... So here's my 2 cents, I've tinkered with PS for a day or so ;-) ... Basically your script has flow control, loops and string manipultions. I'm sure there are PS equivalents for all of that. What may be  difficult is the *nix specific(ish) commands, like `dd`, `shred`. Less so are your compression cmds, `7z` etc, as I believe most of those are easily found for the Windows env.

Comment: Start researching how string substituions work in PS, post a simple Q, "i have this one line of `sh` code, `sed '.....'....` . I tried to get same result in PS with `.....`. Here is the result I'm getting, here is the result I want." You'll need to do this sort of Q for each construct (just once) that your script is using or until you find a better source for info on converting between `.sh` and PS scripting. Good luck.